# Отладка тестов NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь отладить тесты, но при достижении строчки где используется словарь отладчик не может найти Reflect.cs, как избежать этой проблемы и прочих подобных проблем?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь войти внутрь функции, к которой нет исходником. Выходов два: не заходить внутрь (не жмите F11, жмите F10) или найти файл с исходниками.

Comment: Пробовал, он все равно требует.

Comment: У отладки вроде была настройка just my code, поищите в настройках студии

Comment: Да, надо поставить "только мой код", спасибо.

Comment: @Monk ответом мож тогда?

Comment: @Monk ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При отладке есть смысл смотреть только свой код, для этого в студии есть отдельная [настройка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На английском называется Just My Code:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]